# How can I output different value for each input

Tags: jquery, html, foreach

I want to have different value numbers in each `<input>` tag
I have tried this but it produces the same number in all my inputs.
I want each input tag to have a different number.

```
function input() {
    setInterval(function () {
        $("#inp input").each(function () {
            var number=Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
            $("#inp input").val(number)
        })
    },3000)
}
```

How can I output a different number in each input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line `$("#inp input").val(number)` will assign a value to *all* inputs.

`$(this)` should be used to target a single `input` within each iteration of the `each()` function.

```js
input();

function input() {
    setInterval(function () {
        $("#inp input").each(function () {
            var number=Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
            $(this).val(number)
        })
    },3000)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="inp">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: @user864758 don't forget to accept an answer if it helped. This also goes for your previous questions